# Zabbix server failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, zabbix

```
 17460:20220531:100735.556 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 17460:20220531:100735.559 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [1698] Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost'
 17460:20220531:100735.559 Cannot connect to the database. Exiting...
 17479:20220531:100747.806 Starting Zabbix Server. Zabbix 5.0.24 (revision 313ff6504e3).
 17479:20220531:100747.806 ****** Enabled features ******
 17479:20220531:100747.806 SNMP monitoring:           YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 IPMI monitoring:           YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 Web monitoring:            YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 VMware monitoring:         YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 SMTP authentication:       YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 ODBC:                      YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 SSH support:               YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 IPv6 support:              YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 TLS support:               YES
 17479:20220531:100747.806 ******************************
 17479:20220531:100747.806 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 17479:20220531:100747.808 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [1698] Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost'
 17479:20220531:100747.808 Cannot connect to the database. Exiting...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not permissions on zabbix user to database, please go to database and do this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nameofdatabase.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY'passowrd';
```

and then:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` isn't required for `grant` or any user manipulation based `SQL`. Its only there if underlying tables are changed (which shouldn't be needed).